# Recreating the Javascript-powered 360° VR view from the iPad gallery

Tags: javascript, html

On the iPad gallery at http://movies.apple.com/ipad/gallery/ there is a nifty 3D-ish view when you click on the "360°"-Button on the lower right. It seems to be built with Prototype, some custom JS and 180 single JPEGs.
Now, I don't want to steal Apple's code, but I *really* would like to have a similar effect.  I'm afraid recreating the effect all by myself would be too much for me, so 
has anybody ever done something like this and released it as open source (or a paid library or something like this)?  Integration with jQuery would be an added bonus.

Comment: that is cool... It is probably part of the same tool that created the 180 rotated JPEG.

Comment: Thilo: I suppose the JPEGs are just rendered with some 3D software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

> [Reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) is a jQuery plugin which takes an
>   image tag and makes it a live
>   "projection" of pre-built animation
>   frames sequence. Its aim is to provide
>   a 360° view of something or someplace.
>   Great alternative to widely used Flash
>   techniques.

Comment: incredible! How did I miss this while googling for the last half hour?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what ***heporap*** is trying to say is: construct the 3D VR effect in the same way you might make a slider animation.

I guess a slider changes the position of an image in relation to where a mouse cursor is positioned so...

Perhaps try changing the **IMG** tag's **SRC** attribute on ***document.onmousemove*** and ***object.onmousedown*** for drag/positioning effect?

Maybe that sounds obvious, and I'm no maverick coder but it's a start...

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old thread, but its still high on google result.
Here is a jQuery plugin that does exactly that effect http://giniedp.github.com/spritespin/

Answer (score 1):

you better try out threesixty: http://www.mathieusavard.info/threesixty/

Answer (score 0):

You may make it like a slider to change image's src.

http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2010/spins/apple-ipad-us-20100127_512x512/ipad-1up-us-20100127_512x512_172.jpg
http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2010/spins/apple-ipad-us-20100127_512x512/ipad-1up-us-20100127_512x512_135.jpg

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with zoom: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example15.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Rather than just posting a link, please post a relevant snatch of code and some explanation of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Or use [this one](http://www.360-javascriptviewer.com). It's also Javascript but with curves for slowing down and another kinds of zoom functions.